# Is there a pattern/design for transition between two complex system states?

Tags: design-patterns, software-design

I want to know if there is a pattern for the transition between two complex system states.

For example, using Amazon Web Services there is a system called CloudFormation which is your infrastructure defined as JSON.

When you want to update this, you give AWS the desired infrastructure, it knows your current infrastructure, calculates the steps between and performs them. It intelligently makes as few changes as required.

What if any is the common name for this pattern/approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware that there's a consensus term. Chef uses "convergence", and I like that because it conveys the idea that the starting state might or might not be close to the desired state. Puppet uses "apply" and CloudFormation uses "update", neither of which are evocative.

The other example I can think of is database migrations, as found e.g. in Rails. "Migration" means something else in other contexts, so using it to mean applying changes to a database schema was a dubious choice.

Comment: I think it's about as close as we're going to find, I was really hoping to try to find further reading on the concept. Thanks for helping though.